# Packer Ansible host limited variables

Tags: ansible, packer, ansible-inventory

What's the correct approach for handling the need for host bounded variables in packer and its ansible provisioner?

Packer uses ansible provisioner but for CentOS8 / RHEL8 it must set `ansible_python_interpreter` on the CentOS8 host to the platform-python.  However, my playbook has both local and remote steps so I only want to set that variable for that host.  Normally, I don't use an inventory in my provisioner.

```
  "extra_arguments":
  [
    "-v",
    "-e", "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/libexec/platform-python"
  ]
```

I see my options as

- figure out how to pass a host variable via extra_arguments
- setup an inventory via an earlier provisioner and set the variable in that so I can use it later

Please let me know what you've found as a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the packer ansible provisioner [inventory_directory](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html#inventory_directory) will be a key helper.

1. Set inventory_directory option for packer ansible provisioner to define the location of the [ansible inventory directory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) in to which ansible creates an inventory file defining the target host as `default`
2. Populate host variables file for `default` host containing the necessary variable for Centos8/RHEL8's preferred python interpreter

### Packer Provisioner

```
"provisioners": [
  {
    "type": "ansible",
    "playbook_file": "../../../playbooks/linux-agent-provision.yml",
    "inventory_directory": "./inventory",
    "extra_arguments":
    [
      "-v",
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
```

### ./inventory directory

```
inventory/host_vars
inventory/host_vars/default.yml
```

#### inventory/host_vars/default.yml

```
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/libexec/platform-python
```